# Reload DisplayTag Table without refreshing the whole page

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, displaytag

I am developing an application using Spring MVC. I am using DisplayTag Table for pagination. I have quartz job running every 30 seconds which changes some of the fields in my database. So I want the display Tag table to refresh the data by reloading itself without reloading whole page.

I tried the following code

```
$(function()    
 {

   refreshInterval = setInterval(function(){
    $("#displayTagTable Id").load("url for fetching data from db");
  },20000);

 });
```

Above code is not reloading  the Table

I tried with dis code

```
 $(function()   
 {

   refreshInterval = setInterval(function(){
    $("#Id of div Containing DisplayTagTable").load("url for fetching data from db");
  },20000);

 });
```

Its reloading the complete page.
 What is the solution for rloading only displayTag Table?